# Ubuntu not appearing in GRUB menu after installing alonside Mint

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, partitioning, mint

I have been using Mint May 13 for several months, but I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.10 also.  I ran the Ubuntu Live CD and "Installed Alongside".  Everything appeared to install correctly, but when I boot up, it only recognizes Mint and Windows 7(which is on sdb, while Mint and Ubuntu are on sda, with sda first in the boot order.  Mint and win 7 still work fine.  And I examined the partitions on sda and Ubuntu APPEARS to be installed properly.  Is there a step or setting I missed or need to take for GRUB to recognize Ubuntu at boot?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this in a terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reebot and see if it appears in the grub menu.

Comment: Will work on either OS. Choose and remove bootloader package from the other one.